# Property of a positive Lebesgue measure set in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be a closed set of positive Lebesgue measure. Can we find positive Lebesgue measure sets $A_1,A_2\subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $A_1\times A_2\subseteq A$?

Note that the above is not true if $A$ is not assumed to be closed. For example $$A=[0,1]\times [0,1]\setminus \{(x,y)\in [0,1]\times [0,1]:x-y\in \mathbb{Q}\}.$$

Comment: Are you sure that your example of $A$ has positive measure? I am trying to think of your example, particularly the condition $x-y\in\mathbb{Q}$. It is clear on both the $x$ and $y$ axis this amounts to removing all the rationals. Now, if we fix $y\in\mathbb{Q}$ then if $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ then $x-y\in\mathbb{Q}$ so along every horizontal line $y=c$, $0\leq c\leq 1$, we have removed all the rationals and so your set $A$ is essentially all the irrationals in $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ which has zero measure.

Comment: A is positive measure since the set we are removing from unit square is measure zero in R²

Comment: Yes, I have not done measure theory in a while. I had the idea the wrong way around. However, can you tell me what is to stop us from taking $A_{1}$ and $A_{2}$ to be the irrationals between 0 and 1?

Comment: See $\{x-y\in \mathbb{Q}\}$ is set of lines parallel to diagonal interesting axes at rational points. Hence A should not contain any rectangle. Or you can prove rigorously applying Steinhaus theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have an example of a set $A$ of positive measure such $A _1 \times A_2$ is not contained in $A$ for any $A_1$ and $A_2$ of positive measure. By regularity of Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^{2}$ $A$ contains a compact set $K$ of positive measure. It follows that  $A _1 \times A_2$ is not contained in $K$ for any $A_1$ and $A_2$ of positive measure.